# Google analytics track event causing page to change

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript, google-analytics, actionscript-2

I have a flash file and am using google's suggested method for as2 event tracking like so:

```
getURL("javascript:pageTracker._trackEvent('Refferal', 'Join', 'Benefits for HCAs/APs');");
```

The problem is that instead of silently communicating, `pageTracker._trackEvent()` appears to return a boolean value. Every time I click the button which this is located on I leave the page I was on and end up on a page that just contains the word "true".

Does anyone know how to get around this? It makes the flash unusable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your flash is embedded in a web page, you could call a javascript function and let it handle the call to analytics using an external interface:

ExternalInterface.call("myJavaScriptFunction", parameter1, parameter2); (http://geekswithblogs.net/Mikeymac/archive/2006/03/13/72170.aspx)